# What is the plural of status? Is it statuses?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What is the plural of *status*? Is it *statuses* or *status*? If it is *status*, is it pronounce the same is *singuler status*?

[image]

Is there any difference between British and American English regarding this word?

**Update:**

Are the following statements correct? Which one is more formal (in UK English)?

> - These are **statuses** that will typically be assigned to the claim as the
>     claims are processed.
> - These are **status** that will typically be assigned to the claim as the
>     claims are processed.

Comment: Just as a comment, the Google Ngrams can also separately display British English and American English (as well as many other) results for you. Just change the "English" drop-down box to the one you want.

Comment: As for your actual question, there is an answer at our sister site [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-the-plural-form-of-status).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang, Thank you, yes, it is almost the same: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=statuses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstatuses%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Did you look it up in the dictionary, or do a web search for "plural of status"?  What did you find?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-the-plural-form-of-status

Comment: @stangdon I did, it is confused me. it is uncountable and countable in the same time. it is not clear when we can use "statuses", and there are no examples within dictionaries

Comment: @Andrew, thank you, but I don't understand when we can use plural "statuses" or "status"

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+have+different+status%2Cthey+have+different+statuses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20have%20different%20status%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20have%20different%20statuses%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Shannak - Thanks, that helps.  We use "statuses" whenever we're referring to more than one status.  But we don't often need to do that, which is why it's hard to find an example.  Do not expect dictionaries to help you too much; dictionaries provide definitions, not complete instructions for use.  In your update, "These are statuses that will typically be assigned to the claim" looks good to me, because you're talking about more than one possible status.